# How to declare a list with bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using `bootstrap` and I need to implement a list of items to be displayed over many columns.

Bootstrap uses a grid that is 12 cells wide. 
My item being 3 cells wide (that's how I roll), it means that a row holds only 4 items.

```
item 1 | item 2 | item 3 | item 4 
item 5
```

My `item` is not a simple text but a "card" : [image]

The code can be [found there](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/user-profile-widget).

The straightforward way to write this would be:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">[item 1]</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">[item 2]</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">[item 3]</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">[item 4]</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">[item 5]</div>
</div>
```

But it feels non semantic. 
The fact that my items are displayed on many rows is truly pertaining to presentation choices.

Besides, if I now decide that my items should be wider, I have to change the structure of my document (as opposed to class attributes).

Besides that way of doing things is even more artificial on a mobile screen were all my items are displayed on top of each other.

Is there another way to write my list? A more 'semantic' way ?

Comment: What are your "items"? Show some actual code, please, or explain better why this isn't right for your scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my stand, the best way to display an Unordered LIST with hypertext markup is :

```
<ul>
    <li>
```

So, you can try a list of `ul>li`  setting your `<li>` width to 25%, float-left.

Your 5th element is supposed to stack bottom left.

---

If you still want to use bootstrap grid system, just put your 'items' inside the same row.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">item 1</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">item 2</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">item 3</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">item 4</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">item 5</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">item 6</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">item 7</div>
</div>
```

The overflowed elements will be stack bottom left.

So give it a try:

```
<ul class="row">
    <li class="col-md-3">item 1</li>
```

Comment: Indeed, that is working. The nested rows feature does the trick (I messed up the first time I tried it. More info here : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting

Answer (score 3):

You could use a UL list..

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li class="col-md-3">item 1</li>
    <li class="col-md-3">item 2</li>
    <li class="col-md-3">item 3</li>
    <li class="col-md-3">item 4</li>
    <li class="col-md-3">item 5</li>
    <li class="col-md-3">item 6</li>
    <li class="col-md-3">item 7</li>
</ul>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/91825

However, you'd need to change this markup if you decide to make things wider.

Answer (score 1):

1.You can always change the default 12 space grid to whatever you prefer by setting `@gridColumns` to your preference in [this page](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/customize.html) or overriding the css.less if you prefer.

2.With [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#lists) you can use the custom class inline to build your list:

```
<ul class="inline">
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

3.But as Milche refered [col-md-3](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/) will do the trick if you stick to one row. I think I would use a  tag though, to make clear it's inline.

Comment: inline works also. It adds a light margin between the items, and the col-md-3 class seems not necessary on the li.